# how to use Max(sum('salary'))

Tags: mysql

I have a table consists employee salary and years expereince
and I want to get sum of maximum salary for years experience
examples :
I have an employee has 5 years experince and has salary 5000 dollar and another employee has the same of years experince but get 8000 dollar, in this case 8000 dollars will take to sum because it is maximum salary for 5 years experince.
I want to aggregate records based on summation of maximum salary for each years experince
Like this :

```
SELECT SUM(SELECT MAX(salary) from employeeSystem GROUP BY year_experince,salary )
```

Comment: `MAX()` first then subquery it for the `SUM()` afterwards.

Comment: SELECT SUM(SELECT MAX(`salary`)
from employeeSystem
GROUP BY `year_experince`,`salary`
) from employeeSystem
i tried this but it does not work

Comment: could you post the table structure for `employeeSystem` (run `SHOW CREATE TABLE employeeSystem;`) and a few sample data? I'm guessing this would be very easy to do but just in case there is something on that table that we need to be aware of.

Comment: Also, post your expected result (in table form) as well. And please mention your specific MySQL version; you can get from running `SELECT @@version;` or `SELECT version();`